# How do I pull Tomcat 6 parameters from tomcat6w?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat6

I am looking for a way to pull parameters from the tomcat6w.exe program. I've already looked through a bunch of documentation regarding command line parameters in Tomcat but I only see a way to set them and not just view them through the console. What I'm trying to do is pull the parameters into a text file for reference in configuring a new instance of Tomcat on the same/different server. Taking screen shots of each tab in tomcat6w just isn't cutting it :)

I browsed through the Tomcat directory to see if there was a configuration file that had all of these parameters, but I couldn't seem to find one. This is not to say that there isn't one! I've looked through server.xml, web.xml, catalina.properties, and all of the rest of them that I am aware of.

Any help would be appreciated. I might be over-thinking this one and there is probably a simple solution to this, so I apologize in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service settings are stored in the Windows Registry.

Details are documented in the Apache Commons Daemon project that provides the service launcher used by Tomcat, see the last section of
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html

Comment: Thank you Konstantin! I missed this part of the documentation (obviously). I've already written a script that will pull the settings from the registry. I just need to test it a little more before I implement pushing the settings into a new instance of Tomcat. :)